# Improving the NonlinearModelFit

Tags: fitting

I've been trying to fit logarithmic function to the data below:

```
d1 = {{3457, 4.22`}, {3000, 4.33`}, {2500, 4.35`}, {1200, 4.43`}, {600, 4.68`}, {300, 5.8`}, {150, 8.07`}}
```

I used the following code for the fitting:

```
nmf1 = NonlinearModelFit[d1, a + b Log[x], {a, b}, x]

g1 = ListPlot[d1];
g2 = Plot[nmf1[x], {x, 0, 3500}];
Show[g1,g2]
```

where g1 is the $ListPlot$ of the data d1. I got the below fit.
[image]

I am wondering how to improve this fit. The expected function is the natural logarithm, although in this case I managed to do a much better fit with the 1/x. Additionally, I don't have an initial guess at the parameters, which I could use. Any ideas?

Thank you all for help!

Comment: Just an observation: your parameter `c` is redundant.

Comment: Right. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you expect a logarithmic function?

Rational approximation gives a quite good fit:

```
nmf1 = NonlinearModelFit[d1, (a + b x)/(1 + c x), {a, b, c}, x,Method -> "NMinimize"];
Show[{ListPlot[d1],Plot[Normal[nmf1], {x, 150, 3500}, PlotRange -> All]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I just realized that my model was incorrect. I expected the logarithm, but for the inverse values of y. Still, your solution was and will be helpful in my analysis. May I ask - is the NMinimize the method of least-squares or something else?

Comment: Usually I use "NMinimize" as a robust solver if I don't no initial parameter values. Don't no which method is used.

Comment: Alright, will look into documentation. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome!